# iPhone - why are some methods declared on .m and not on .h?

Tags: iphone

I am creating a new file using Xcode's navigation based application and I see that the .m file has these lines:

```
@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

Why is that declared on .m and not on .h itself?

wouldn't it be easier to just put one line (this one below) on the header file?

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

I have seen this kind of approach in other codes. I am still learning Objective-C and I wonder why is that.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not putting it into the public interface of the class, you're essentially making a method private (it doesn't prevent people outside of your class from calling it if they really want to, but at least it causes a compiler warning).

```
@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

is a class extension (= an anonymous category; a "normal" category would have a category name in between the `()`). It purpose is to declare the private methods (otherwise you'd get a compiler warning if you're trying to call `configureCell:atIndexPath:` in the `.m` file prior to its implementation).

You can read more about categories and class extensions [in the developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html)

Comment: but why would Apple bother to do that in a template?

Comment: So that you'll wonder what this is good for, ask, and learn something about good coding style ;)

Answer (score 3):

Public methods go in the .h file, putting private ones in the .m file hides them from other classes.

Comment: To add, there are no private methods in Objective-C. So empty categories in the `.m` files are used to declare the `private` methods.

Comment: but why would Apple bother to do that in a template?

Comment: Because it is really really useful;  it allows you to easily separate/organize public API vs. stuff only your class should use.